# Define question environment in lyx

Tags: lyx, environments, exam, layout

Maybe this is a simple question, but I don't know the layouts in lyx.

How can I write `questions` and `choices` environments (with `\CorrectChoice`) in a `lyx` layout?

```
\documentclass{exam}
   
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{questions}
    \question
    What is the first letter?
    \begin{choices}
    \CorrectChoice A
    \choice B
    \choice C
    \end{choices}
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which package/class is that syntax defined by?

Comment: The `exam` class. A latex document begins with `\documentclass{exam}`.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/fuhrmanator/lyx-layouts? (via https://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Layouts via google)

Comment: Yes, I looked at it. But he defined new commands like `\myquestion` and `\mychoice`. In his template, `lyx` does not know `\question`, `\choice` and `\CorrectChoice`. He defined some commands that match `\item` to `\choice` and `\CorrectChoice`. I would like to use a layout that directly uses `\choice` and `\CorrectChoice`.